# Use jq to add string to each element of a list

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

I would like to write all the direcory names of a parent inside a list.
I'm using the tree command to achieve this as well as jq.

That's what I have so far:

```
directories_found=$(tree -J -d -L 1 | jq -c '.[0].contents | map(.name)').map(.name)
```

The tree comand returns this before the pipe:

```
directories_found=[{"type":"directory","name": ".","contents":[ {"type":"directory","name":"AppBackend","contents":[ ]}, {"type":"directory","name":"list-folder-action","contents":[ ]} ]}, {"type":"report","directories":2} ]
```

And then, after applying jq, the output I see is this:

```
["AppBackend","list-folder-action"]
```

Looks awesome. But I'd like to edit these values but also keep the list structure.

My goal is to add a chunk of text before each element, like this:

```
["example/AppBackend","example/list-folder-action"]
```

I just started using jq. How could I do this?

Comment: Instead of just mapping the array of objects to one its fields with `map(.name)`, extend the filter within the mapping to perform other operations too, as in `map("example/" + .name)`.

Comment: Do you only want to add "example/" unconditionally or do you want to get a list of "paths", e.g. "example/this/is/a/nested/directory"?

Comment: I just wanted to add "example/" unconditionally. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a supplement to @pmf's answer, it is perhaps worth mentioning that
you can specify the prefix on the command-line.  Also, if you wanted to keep the tree structure, you could run jq like so:

```
jq -c --arg prefix example/ '.[0].contents |= map($prefix + .name)'
```